# Can I change the default control style of PS One Classics?

Tags: ps3, ps1

I recently bought Parasite Eve on PSN for my PS3. This is a PS1 game. It comes complete with old style gameplay, obviously outdated graphics, and all the nostalgia that comes with it.

When I boot it up to play, the first thing I make note to do is change the Controller Setting for Analog mode. On the PS1 this was not a problem. There was a dedicated button on the controller to turn thumbstick operation on and off. On the PS3? Not so much...

On the PS3 you press the Playstation button in the middle of the controller, go into Controller Settings, and change "Switch Analog Mode" from Analog Mode to Digital Mode. This turns off the thumbstick operation for moving and switches it back to the classic PS1 digital keypad for moving.

While this works nicely and all... I would like to find a way to make this the default mode for at least this game, if not all PS1 Classics.

**How do I change the default setting for PS1 Analog Mode on the PS3?**

Comment: I have never been able to save it either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (coming from a guy that has probably 50+ PSN PS1 games downloaded on my PS3), there is no default way to change the controller setup like so.

I always adjust my graphics (smoothing and full screen) every time I launch a game. I know it's annoying... but hey, I'm glad we can still play some of our favorite games.

Comment: That's EXTREMELY unfortunate... You would think something like this would be standard fare... Ah, well. Not that big a deal in the grand scheme of things. Thank you!